# Right click on linkbutton and select "open in new window" opening blank page

Tags: asp.net, button

I have link button. Onclick event of this button, i am filling a session value and redirecting to other page. But my problem is, while right clicking on that button and selecting "open in new window" option, page is redirecting to blank page.

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onclick event won't fire when you open a new tab, or middle click on it.
You can take care of it manually, however, like this:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "a", function(e) {
   if( e.which === 3 || e.which === 2) { // 3 = right click, 2 = middle click
      e.preventDefault();
         // do your thing      
   }
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7kLX6/)